# Insert new user in database with sequelize does not save values

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Im trying to create a new user with sequelize.
When I run the code, I get this result :

```
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `email` `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `password` `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `createdAt` `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `updatedAt` `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
Table and model synced successfully !
```

It seems like the values are not saved in the database. What should I do to fix that ?
If you need more details about the code feel free to ask in comment, I don't know what to add here to be more clear ^^.

My whole code :

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const connexion = require("../database");

const User = connexion.define(
  "users",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },

    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
    },

    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true  
  }
);

User.sync({ alter: true })
  .then(() => {
    const user = User.build({
      email: "michel@google.com",
      password: "framboise",
    });
    return user.save();
  })

  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Table and model synced successfully !");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Sync error");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by doing this :

```
User.create({ email: "rodriguez@google.com", password: "citrouille" })

    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user);
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Sync error");
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).